# How to add payment method field to the footer of an order summary view?

Tags: 7, commerce

I can add payment method field to fields in my view, but it is not available to add in footer.

Why is it? How could I add it this field in the footer view?

**Note**:  My view is an order summary view, showing all line items, I would like to display below of the lite items, what was the payment method used. I think the footer would be a nice place to put this information, but I don't see the token for it. I can see the token to add in fields but not in footer.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @nvahalik My view is an order summary view, showing all line items, I would like to display below of the lite items, what was the payment method used. I think the footer would be a nice place to put this information, but I don't see the token for it. I can see the token to add in fields but not in footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it? Fields are meant to go in the fields section and not in the footer.

An easy workaround solution is to create an attachment view contenting only the field in question and attach it after your current view.

1. To do this, in your view, click on +Add and select attachment.

[image]

2. Then you should have a cloned copy of your original view. When you add or remove fields make sure you select at top **This attachment (override)**. If you do not do this, your changes will affect all of your views.

[image]

3. In your first/original view: In footer click on Add and select Global: View area. Select your attachment view and check mark the inherit contextual filters box.

[image]

> **Note:** If your first/original view is a Master, when you add the attachment, you will not have the **For:
>   Display** box, [image] such as in the last picture (on step 3).
>
> If that is the case, all your views will get an attachment, including the 
>   attachment. Therefore, you will have to switch to the attachment view and 
>   select "This attachment (override)" and remove the footer from the attachment.

Comment: ah yes thank you @No Sssweat for remember it to me, I am new here! Kind regards